# Is Autumn being referred to by the female pronoun 她? Is this normal?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

This is from my 3-rd grade 语文 book (there's a version [here](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/9793ce65b84ae45c3b358c8b.html)):

> 现在正是金秋时节。我们已经看到了她缤纷的色彩， 听见了她美妙的声音，分享了她带给我们的欢乐。

I translate this to:

> It's currently Golden Autumn.  We already see her diverse ([缤纷](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%BC%A4%E7%BA%B7)的) colors ([色彩](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%89%B2%E5%BD%A9)), heard her wonderful ([美妙](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%BE%8E%E5%A6%99)的) sounds ([声音](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%A3%B0%E9%9F%B3)), [and] shared ([分享](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%88%86%E4%BA%AB)了) the joy ([欢乐](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%AC%A2%E4%B9%90)) she provides us ([带给](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B8%A6%E7%BB%99)我们的).

I think I've managed to understand it correctly, but it looks like "Golden Autumn" (金秋时节) is being referred to using the female pronoun 她 (instead of "it" 它), perhaps for poetic reasons, or perhaps this is normal.  I just want to check this.

**Question**: Is Autumn being referred to by the female pronoun 她?  Is this normal?

Comment: Maybe related: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/17727/4136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is a very common way to refer something to pronoun 她 in Chinese, commonly known as personification. In such a way, the author can strengthen his/her feelings about autumn. There are also many similar cases: such as 长江/黄河/故乡(Yangzi River/Yellow River/hometown) can often be referred to 她 as well.