# Should I use 她 or 它 for 中国? (and/or other countries)

Tags: word-choice, poetry, pronouns, style

If you're writing romantically, would 中国/中华 be 她 or 它?

Comment: Female 她 might be the option, see: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17727/she-%e5%a5%b9-for-inanimate-objects-in-chinese

Comment: It is very difficult to link "它" to something "romantic", although it is the pronoun for everything lifeless.

Comment: @r13 Lifeless? A dog or a cat is lifeless? Perhaps you mean non-human?

Comment: @NanningYouth Strickly/acdemically speaking, you are correct. But in the real living world, a dog/cat/pet is often referred to as he/she or him/her in literature to express fondness for the animal. An answer to the query "所有動物都可以用 he 或 she 來指稱嗎?" - "可以的！在中文中，貓和狗通常被稱為她/他。這是一種將動物視為有性別的方式，並且在日常對話中很常見。" (https://blog.cybertranslator.idv.tw/archives/5647)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe 其 would be best? In my opinion, 其 sounds more romantic than 她 or 它.

In my opinion, 其 looks cute!

The old character (从竹丌象形) seems to represent a basket on a table. How that came to be a Third Person Pronoun is a mystery to me!

其 has the advantage of being genderless, or gender fluid, so you do not have to decide which gender 中国 is. This is ancient political correctness in practice! Your Western mind asks: Is 中国 male, female or neuter? This question did not arise in bygone China!

其  has the advantage of grammatical case fluidity. 其 can represent what in other languages might be nominal case or oblique case.

中国将会利用其影响力帮助推进和平进程。
China will use her influence to help push forward the peace process.

中国是一个古老的国家，其历史延续了五千年。
As an ancient country, China's history stretches over five thousand years.

Some suggestions:

彼: 彼，对此称彼也。——《玉篇》

其:
1. 彼、他 [he]
2. 她 [she]。如:萨奇打他的妻子，将其打倒在地
3. 它 [it] 或者不如说希望:希望其有，又希望其无。——鲁迅《祝福》
4. 他们;她们;它们 [they]。如:避其锐气，击其惰归
5. 他的 [his] 他日归，则有馈其兄生鹅者。——《孟子·滕文公下》
6. 又如:其妻
7. 她的 [her]。如:其夫
8. 它的 [its]。如:鸟之将死，其鸣也哀
9. 他们的;她们的;它们的 [their]。如:他们思想保守，固守其老一套做法

之:
1. 指代人或事物的名称，相当于他、她、它、他们 [he;her;it;they;them]
2. 指示代词，相当于“其”、“他的”、“其他的” [its;his;other]

I have never made an exhaustive study of 其, but it seems to me 其 is at least mostly used in phrases where Western languages would use an oblique case form. Notwithstanding, I believe most people would say Chinese has no "grammatical case, 语法格"

Answer (score 0):

Both she and it are acceptable in modern standard chinese, depending on the mood of the text, and this is a function shared with english.  "It" is acceptable when being referred to as an "inatimate object" of "land". "She" is acceptable when being referred to as a "motherland" or "homeland" type entity, especially in formal or poetic contexts.

However, there is a strong caveat.  The entire concept of he vs she vs it is pretty modern to chinese as a whole.  Most types of chinese, including literary and older chinese, only have a single pronoun used for all. In that context this question is N/A since there is no multiple choice.